# How can I change this assembly code to mod this video game?

Tags: assembly, 3d, ollydbg

This is perhaps an unusual question, but I will appreciate any help.

First of all, I am not a programmer and never studied programming, but I have some amateur knowledge of Visual Basic and Java.

I have been trying to mod an old video game called "Tomb Raider III."

This is a 3d game in which a woman called Lara fights against some creatures. You can see the game in [this video clip](http://youtu.be/HuzCz3QVvqo) (scroll to minute 5:00 to see how she fights with the tiger as an example).

What I want to do is to mod the game so that the enemy creatures can do more damage to Lara's health when they hit her.

The file that runs the game is called "tomb3.exe". I opened this file with the disassembler OllyDbg. I was very lucky to find a command line that is apparently responsible for making damage to Lara's health when she is hit by enemies. When I replaced this line by "NOP'S" (i.e, deleted it), Lara became invincible. She was no longer hurt by enemy strikes. The tiger (for example) would keep hitting her but her health would not be affected.

[This image](http://www.imagebam.com/image/cc11cc321307431) shows the line I am talking about. It is located at 004205EC.

The code between 004205BD and 004205CF is responsible for making the enemies strike Lara. When I deleted this code, the tiger would run towards Lara as if it is attacking her, but it would not bite or scratch her.

The lines that seem to be responsible for damage caused by the enemy attacks are those:

```
CMP WORD PTR DS:[ESI+12],AX

MOV WORD PTR DS:[ESI+E],AX
```

I tried (in many ways) to edit these lines, but I could not make them work after editing them. I just don't know enough to do it.

What I want is to **increase** the damage caused by enemy attacks (say double it, or triple it). I thought that AX might contain the value of the damage (or perhaps the value of Lara's health?). I tried to change the value of AX by using commands such as "imul AX, 2", but that only caused the game to crash at the moment an enemy appeared to Lara.

I know that this is a weird question, but any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I want to explain something. The code that I referred to in this question is responsible for the different animations that a terrestrial enemy can do when attacking Lara. The specific line that I highlighted is responsible for the terminal action that a terrestrial enemy does when attacking Lara. For men with guns this action is represented by the movement of the bullets out of the guns towards Lara's body. Thus, disabling this line will disable the bullets animation, and Lara will not get hurt. This code is about the animations of the terrestrial enemies when they are in the attack mode. I don't think that it is responsible for Lara's health or the strength of the enemy attacks. I have yet to discover the code that is responsible for those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if the code is using a lookup table telling it how much damage each type of enemy causes. You could try to change that table. It is accessed in the preceding line, the `mov ax, word ptr ds:[eax+6]`. At that point `eax` seems to contain a pointer to the enemy struct, in which the damage value is a word at offset 6. Stop execution on that line, then you should see what `eax+6` is, and edit the value in memory at that address.

**Update**
If you have space elsewhere, then overwrite the `CMP` and the `MOV` with a `JMP elsewhere` and at `elsewhere` you can double `AX` by doing

```
ADD AX, AX
CMP WORD PTR DS:[ESI+12],AX
MOV WORD PTR DS:[ESI+E],AX
JMP 004205F0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. Unfortunately, I don't know how to run the game with OllyDbg. When I run the debug, the game will not start. If I press f8, the debug will move for a few lines and then enters into a loop and will not get out of it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line in question, and just let it run.

Comment: I toggled a breakpoint at that line, but when I run it will start from the beginning, despite the break point. I managed to run the "tomb3.exe" with the debug, but what appears is the game setup screen (resolution setting etc.). When I press ok to exit that screen, the game crashes. This does not happen when I start it outside of OllyDbg.

Comment: Could you clarify to me where exactly I should see the eax+6? In the registry panel there is EAX. It has 8 digits. Is eax+6 the last two digits from the left?

Comment: No, `eax+6` is just that. Add `6` to the value of `eax` that you see.

Comment: I appreciate all your help, but this method is not working for me because I am unable to run the game in the debug. Is there a way to modify the value of AX by adding some code to the original code (for example, a code that multiplies AX by 2). If this is possible, could you write for me this additional code and tell me where I should put it? I can keep the total file size unchanged by deleting some of the NOP's that are scattered in it.

Comment: Thank you Jester for your help. I have made some experiments with the line "mov ax, word ptr ds:[eax+6]" and it seems to me that AX in this line is not simply a pointer to the enemy hit-strength. When I changed the number 6 to 8 or 9 the result was that the terrestrial enemies (like the monkeys and tigers) flew in the air in a horizontal position with their backs facing the ground and their limbs moving as if they were swimming. I don't understand what this is exactly, but it seems that AX is not simply about hit strength.